# Thermal efficiency of a furnace reactor?

Tags: chemical-engineering

I'm doing plant design and one of the reactors is a furnace that uses methane to burn. I want to calculate the amount of methane that is required. I have the energy needed and the calorific value of methane but now I need a average thermal efficiency. Just to be clear I want the ratio of energy produced over how much was put in. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The efficiency depends on how well-insulated the reactor is, and how complete the burn is. But broadly speaking, something between 80% and 100%. It also depends on whether you're recovering heat by condensing the water vapour - if not, you want to use the LHV (rather than the HHV) of methane (or equivalently, de-rate the HHV by 10%)